# Nested select eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible creating nested select in Eloquent using query builder? I have problem where i need to group and use sum on one column of my table but that column is displayed as debit or credit and depends on another column value. I need to group one more time to get both of the sums in one row.

```
$columns=array( DB::raw('left(archive_ledgers.account,3) as account'),
        DB::raw('(case when archive_ledgers.booking_type=1 then sum(archive_ledgers.amount) else 0 end) as debit'),
        DB::raw('(case when archive_ledgers.booking_type!=1 then sum(archive_ledgers.amount) else 0 end) as credit')
       );
ArchiveLedger::where('accounts.account_type', '<=', $accounts['to'])
                    ->join('accounts',function($join){
                        $join->on('archive_ledgers.account','=','accounts.account');
                    })
                    ->join('orders',function($join){
                        $join->on('orders.id','=','archive_ledgers.order_id');
                    })
                    ->where('archive_ledgers.account', '>=', $accounts['from'])
                    ->where('document_date', '<=', Input::get('dateTo'))
                    ->where('document_date', '>=', Input::get('dateFrom'))
                    ->select($columns)
                    ->orderBy('archive_ledgers.booking_type',DB::raw('left(archive_ledgers.account,3)'))
                    ->groupBy('archive_ledgers.booking_type',DB::raw('left(archive_ledgers.account,3)'));
```

I need to do select on result given from this query

```
select `account`, sum(s1.owes) as owes, sum(s1.asks) as asks, s1.owes - s1.asks as total from (select left(archive_ledgers.account,3) as account, (case when archive_ledgers.booking_type=1 then sum(archive_ledgers.amount) else 0 end) as owes, (case when archive_ledgers.booking_type!=1 then sum(archive_ledgers.amount) else 0 end) as asks from `archive_ledgers` inner join `accounts` on `archive_ledgers`.`account` = `accounts`.`account` inner join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = `archive_ledgers`.`order_id` where `accounts`.`account_type` <= ? and `archive_ledgers`.`account` >= ? and `document_date` <= ? and `document_date` >= ? group by `archive_ledgers`.`booking_type`, left(archive_ledgers.account,3) order by `archive_ledgers`.`booking_type` desc) s1 group by `s1`.`account`)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `nested select`? Write your query in SQL

Comment: If the query is of a big complexity, why don't you just write it in plain SQL? This is certainly not very readable anyway.

Comment: Query added to the question. I can write raw sql but i need nested select for other queries

Comment: I solved the problem. It bit manual but it has most of the automation i need